# can someone tell me why my js code is not printing the date using the arrow function?

Tags: javascript, datetime, oop, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

```js
const datee = () => document.write(new Date());

datee; //no response, same for console.log

const datei = () => new Date();

console.log(datei); // () => new Date();
```

The comments above shows what they are printing if they are printing anything

Comment: You forgot to call any of the functions

Comment: In the dev-tools console on this page, `const datee = () => document.write(new Date()); console.log(datee)` for me shows _"() => document.write(new Date())"_

Comment: how do i fix it? how do i get the date??

Comment: you need to execute the function 
`var a  =  () => console.log(new Date());
a();`

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here. Are you asking about the _"no response, same for console.log"_ where you would expect to see the function definition logged or are you asking about why your script isn't executing `document.write(new Date())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the arrow functions just like a regular inline function

```
const datei = () => new Date();
console.log(datei()); // returns Date Object;

// Hovwever, without calling (without "()")
const datei = () => new Date();
console.log(datei); // () => new Date();
```

Comment: this worked, i needed to add the brackets as we do for calling a function